# Klein–Gordon Inner Product in Reissner–Nördstrom Spacetime

Tags: quantum-field-theory, black-holes, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

We consider a massless charged scalar field $\Phi$ on the Reissner–Nördstrom black hole space:

$$ds^2=-f(r)dt^2+f(r)^{-1}dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2\theta\,d\varphi^2, \tag{1}$$

with $f(r)=1-\frac{2M}{r}+\frac{Q^2}{r^2}$ and known horizons $r_\pm=M\pm\sqrt{M^2-Q^2}$. The dynamics of the scalar field is determined by

$$g^{\mu\nu}D_\mu D_\nu\Phi=0,\quad\text{with}\quad D_\mu=\nabla_\mu-iq A_\mu,\quad\text{and }\quad A_\mu=\left(-\frac{Q}{r},0,0,0\right). \tag{2}$$

The scalar field modes can be written as

$$\phi_{\omega\ell m}=\frac{e^{-i\omega t}}{r}\mathcal{N}_\omega X_{\omega\ell}(r)Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\varphi), \tag{3}$$

where $\ell=0,1,\dots$, $m=-\ell,\dots,\ell$; $X_{\omega\ell}(r)$ are radial functions, $Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\varphi)$ are the usual spherical harmonics and **$\mathcal{N}_{\omega}$ is a normalization factor, which is the point of my question**.

The tortoise coordinate $r_{\ast}$ is defined as $dr_{\ast}=f(r)^{-1}dr$, which lead to the following radial equation:

$$\left(-\frac{d^2}{dr_{\ast}^2}+V(r)\right)X_{\omega\ell}=0, \tag{4}$$

with a potential that has the following asymptotic values:

$$V(r)=\begin{cases}
-\tilde{\omega}=-\left(\omega-\frac{qQ}{r_+}\right), & \text{ if } r_\ast\rightarrow-\infty\;(r\rightarrow r_+)  \\ 
-\omega, & \text{ if } r_\ast\rightarrow+\infty\;(r\rightarrow\infty)
\end{cases}. \tag{5}$$

The asymptotic behavior of the radial part of the solution modes is the following:

$$X_{\omega\ell}^{(in)}(r)=\begin{cases}
T^{(in)}_{\omega\ell}e^{-i\tilde{\omega}r_\ast}, & \text{ if } r_\ast\rightarrow-\infty\;(r\rightarrow r_+)  \\ 
\boxed{I^{(in)}_{\omega\ell}e^{-i\omega r_\ast}}+R^{(in)}_{\omega\ell}e^{i\omega r_\ast}, & \text{ if } r_\ast\rightarrow+\infty\;(r\rightarrow\infty)
\end{cases}, \tag{6}$$

which are called **in modes** represents to waves incoming from the **past null infinity**, are partly reflected back to the *future null infinity* and also partly transmitted to the *future horizon*. In the same way, the so-called **up modes**:

$$X_{\omega\ell}^{(up)}(r)=\begin{cases}
\boxed{I^{(up)}_{\omega\ell}e^{i\tilde{\omega}r_\ast}}+R^{(up)}_{\omega\ell}e^{-i\tilde{\omega}r_\ast}, & \text{ if } r_\ast\rightarrow-\infty\;(r\rightarrow r_+)  \\ 
T^{(up)}_{\omega\ell}e^{i\omega r_\ast}, & \text{ if } r_\ast\rightarrow+\infty\;(r\rightarrow\infty)
\end{cases}, \tag{7}$$

which represent waves outgoing near the **past event horizon**, partly reflected back to the *future horizon* and party transmitted to the *future null infinity*.

**Question:**

To find the normalization constant $\mathcal{N}_{\omega}$, it is defined the **Klein-Gordon inner product** as

$$\langle\Phi_1\Phi_2\rangle=i\int_\Sigma\left(\left(D_\mu\Phi_1\right)^\ast\Phi_2-\Phi_1^\ast\left(D_\mu\Phi_2\right)\right)\sqrt{-g}\;d\Sigma^\mu, \tag{8}$$

where I know that $d\Sigma^\mu=d\Sigma\;n^\mu$. The statement says that *by using a Cauchy surface close to the union of the past event horizon and past null infinity for the in and up modes*, we find, as computed in [this paper (eq. 16)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.01630)

$$\mathcal{N}_{\omega\ell}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi|\omega|}}, \tag{9}\label{9}$$

which seems to be a quick exercise of computation as in the *flat* KG inner product computed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/321650/klein-gordon-inner-product) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51422/klein-gordon-inner-product?rq=1). I dont understand the configuration previous to the computation: *a Cauchy surface close to the union of the **past event horizon** and **past null infinity***, and how this would lead to \eqref{9}.

**EDIT: Use the Penrose diagram:**

My reasoning is as follows. In the Penrose diagram for a RN black hole,

[image: penrose_RN_bh]

I must choose a Cauchy surface near the past null infinite and the past event horizon. So, it seems that I must consider **only the $I_{\omega\ell}^{in/up}$ parts of the "waves", and then to compute the KG inner product**. But it is weird to me to have a Cauchy surface near that regions. Also, **I dont know if my arrowed waves (red/blue) depicting the process are correct**.

Comment: Maybe it will help if you provided a link to the original paper/book where you got the above calculations. Someone may find the answer given the entire context of the particular article.

Comment: @josephh, of course. Just edited my question.

Comment: Is your green curve the Cauchy surface You have in mind ? I would have thought it should belong to region I, very close to the past horizon and the past null infinity, but "above" them

Comment: @AlanGarbarz, yes; indeed, it is very close and above the intersection between the past horizon and the past null infinity. It was a drawing mistake. I will correct the picture. thanks